# Getting "implicit assignment of unexported field"

Tags: go

```
package main
```

main.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "practice/pkg"
)

func main() {
    mk := pkg.MustKey{map[string]string{"Hello": "bar"}}
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", mk)
}
```

pkg package

hello.go

```
package pkg

type MustKey struct {
    m map[string]string
}
```

While executing the following, I am getting error as mentioned in the subject line. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

There is a very important rule in Go - how to Export/unexport any functions/methods/fields.

- **E**xport - when the name starts with a Captial letter (say it Public)
- **u**nexport - when the name starts with a small letter (say it Private)

So in your case, the struct type name `MustKey` is exportable (starts with a capital `M`) and can be accessed outside your defined package `pkg`. But the map variable `m` inside the struct does start with a small `m`, so it cannot be accessed outside the package and private to that package only.

So, you have 2 solutions:

1. Either use `M` instead of `m`, like:

```
    type MustKey struct {
        M map[string]string
    }
```

2. Or, if you still want the map variable private - use Exported methods with helping of interface

```
    type MustKey struct {
        m map[string]string
    }

    func (mk *MustKey) GetValue(key string) (string, error) {
        value, ok := m[key]
        if !ok {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Key is not available: %s", key)
        }
        return value, nil
    }

    func (mk *MustKey) SetValue(key, value string) {
        m[key] = value
    }
```

*And you can use these Get and Set methods to put your own logic.*

[Read](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/03/exportedunexported-identifiers-in-go.html) this for good understanding.

Answer (score 5):

In this code:

```golang
type MustKey struct {
   m map[string]string
}
```

the map variable is in lower case so it is un-exported (and only private to that package). In Golang to export any field from one pkg to another it should me in Upper case.

Two solutions:

1) Declare Map fields in Upper case, eg:

```golang
type MustKey struct {
   // m map[string]string
   // Upper case fields can be export to other packages
   M map[string]string 
}
```

2) Wrap your structure in one function and export the function name.

Answer (score 3):

`MustKey.m` is an unexported field. You are attempting to initialize that field without referring to it by name with  `pkg.MustKey{map[string]string{"Hello": "bar"}}`.

You either have to export the field by renaming it to `M`, or you have to define a constructor function that will set it in the package:

```
func NewMustKey(m map[string]string) MustKey {
   return MustKey{m:m}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The field `m` in the MustKey struct is lower case. Therefore it is an unexported field and cannot be used by a program that imports the pkg package. Unexported fields have to be operated on by methods or functions that are internal to the pkg package. Or change it to an `M` and then use that externally.

You are implicitly using `m` when you do the initialization in main.